# In Cocoa, how can my NSView receive an event when the mouse is held down (but not moved)?

Tags: cocoa, events, mouse, tracking

I'm looking for the right way to handle "mouse held down in one spot" events in my `NSView` subclass.

I am familiar with Cocoa's `mouseDragged:` event, but it is only triggered when the mouse moves. If the mouse stays in the same position, no drag event is triggered. Similarly, `mouseDown:` is only fired when the button is first pressed. My view needs to perform an action as long as the mouse is held down in a particular region.

What is the proper way to do this kind of thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you start performing the action when you receive a `mouseDown:` event, and stop when you receive `mouseUp:` (or `mouseDragged:`, if you want to stop then, too)?

Comment: +1 That would certainly work. I guess I'm just surprised that there isn't a built-in Event or method for handling that kind of thing. I was expecting an event something like `mouseStillDown:`

Comment: Sorry for the long delay, and thank you for your answer. This ended up being the solution that I used.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to accomplish, but if you want an action to be repeated at set time intervals after the `mouseDown:`, you could set a recurring NSTimer in the `mouseDown:` method that gets cancelled as soon as there is a `mouseDragged:` or `mouseUp:` event.